# Midnight Omniprescence

Tags: knowledge, music

Here's some things I kept in my basement for a while.

1. a scroll
2. a flower pot
3. a vase
4. a bust of a woman's head
5. a ballerina dress
6. a blank canvas

Weirdly, these are the only things I can remember.

**By this information, what musician was I listening to? (7, 5, 5)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were listening to the musician

> [Leyland James Kirby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Caretaker_(musician))

Because these six items

> are seen on his work [Everywhere at the End of Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everywhere_at_the_End_of_Time) comprised of six stages (portraying the progression of Alzheimer's disease). The cover art for stage 1 is **a scroll**, stage 2 **a flower pot**, stage 3 **a vase**, stage 4 **a bust of a woman's head**, stage 5 **a ballerina dress**, stage 6 **a blank canvas**.

Here is an image

> of the cover art for the six stages:
> [image]
> which you can find here: [Cover art - stage 1-6](https://lhsledger.org/2399/entertainment/everywhere-at-the-end-of-time-overview-and-analysis/)

Comment: After seeing the solution, this seems to be a trivia question more than it is a puzzle.